# Having Trouble Implementing toString() Method in (Java)

Tags: java, tostring

I am writing a program that uses two different classes. One class contains the main method and the other class is a generic class Set  that has a set of items of generic type T which uses ArrayList.

This program finds the intersection of two sets.

I want to use the toString() method but I don't know how to implement it in this specific situation when the data fields are not visible.

```
import java.util.Random;

//Generic class Set<T>
class Set <T>
{

    ArrayList<T> num = new ArrayList<T>();

    /*Within this class I have (1) an add method, (2) a remove method, 
    and  (3) a method that returns true if the item is in the set and
    false if it is not in the set*/

    //This is the intersection method
    public static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> k, Set<T> p){

        Set<T> abc = new Set<T> ();
        /*I have some other codes here to find the intersection
         of two different sets*/

    return abc;
    }


    @Override
    /*Here is where I am completely lost
    I do not know how to use this method in order to print
    out the intersection of both sets*/

    public String toString() {      
    /*I don't know what to implement here in order to return
    a string that represents the current object*/
    return;
    }
}


public class SecondClass {
//MAIN METHOD
     public static void main(String [] args){   

     /* This program generates random numbers
     for two sets in order to find the
     intersection of both sets. */

     Set<Integer> firstSet = new Set<Integer>();
     Set<Integer> secondSet = new Set<Integer>();
     Set<Integer> result = new Set<Integer>();


     result = Set.intersection(firstSet,secondSet);



      //Display intersection?
      System.out.println(result.toString());

     }
}
```

Comment: Note that there is already a standard interface named `Set`: `java.util.Set`. It's not a good idea to give your own class the same name as something in the standard Java library - it can lead to confusing error messages. Rename your class to something else than `Set`.

Comment: It depends how you want the String-representation of your object to look like. There is not really a single correct answer, though I want to note that toString should not be used to control your logic-flow (e.g. by identifying/comparing objects with it), so if that is what youre aiming for - dont :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "when the data fields are not visible"?

Comment: @LionC is there another effective option to consider?

Comment: @SdlS Well, use the Objects fields/methods to work with it. Implement equals() to compare, implement methods for specific comparisons that you need. Just do not use toString to control your logic, or youre probably gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using an `ArrayList` as your backing data structure. It has a well-implemented `toString()`, so why not just delegate to it?

```
@Override public String toString() { return num.toString(); }
```